# SSRS ramdomly stops working

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hopefully someone has seen this.  When I google I see this error back in 2009/2010 with SQL Server 2008, but nothing recent.  I also don't see any solutions that work.

I'm using IIS8, SQL Server 2014, Reporting Services 2014.

Reports will be working fine, then they just stop.  I don't see any pattern yet to when they fail.  At least every morning I have to restart, sometimes as much as 3 times a day.  When it stops the only way I can get them to start working is to:

1. Restart the service.
2. Before trying to run a report or anything else, browse to localhost/reports and make sure the folders show up.

If I try and run a report from our app before doing the above two steps, it will not work and I need to repeat those two steps.

When it stops working, I can not even browse to localhost/reports.  Will not even give me a folder list.  Once I go through the steps above everything works great.  Sometimes all day, sometimes until evening.

Here is the error in the log.  Again, reports work great after restarting, sometimes all day.

> library!ReportServer_0-3!1e9c!07/09/2015-21:24:54:: e ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException:
>   ,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException:
>   An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for
>   more details. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.UpgradeScripts,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. Access is denied. File name:
>   'Microsoft.ReportingServices.UpgradeScripts, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.get_ReportingServicesVersionNumber()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.IsUpToDateDatabaseVersion(String
>   storedDBVersion)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.EnsureCorrectDBVersion()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.ConnectStorage(VersionVerificationOptions
>   option)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.VerifyConnection()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Storage.NewStandardSqlCommand(String
>   storedProcedureName)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.CachedSystemProperties.GetSystemProperty(String
>   name)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.CachedSystemProperties.Get(String
>   name, Boolean noThrow)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.CachedSystemProperties.GetParameter(String
>   name)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RSService.get_MyReportsEnabled()
>   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RSService.PathToInternal(String
>   source)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.CatalogItemContext.SetPath(String
>   path, String editSessionID, ItemPathOptions options)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RSService.ConstructItemContext(String
>   path, Boolean allowEditSession, String parameterName)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.SessionStarterAction.CreateNew(SessionfulClientRequest
>   session, RSService service, String reportPath, String historyId)
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
>   library!ReportServer_0-3!145c!07/09/2015-21:25:51:: e ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException:
>   ,
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException:
>   The report server cannot open a connection to the report server
>   database. A connection to the database is required for all requests
>   and processing. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.UpgradeScripts,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. Access is denied. File name:
>   'Microsoft.ReportingServices.UpgradeScripts, Version=12.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.get_ReportingServicesVersionNumber()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.ConnectStorage(VersionVerificationOptions
>   option)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.get_Connection()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.RunningJobsDb.GetMyRunningJobs(JobTypeEnum
>   runningJobType)

Comment: have you googled the error `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.UpgradeScripts`? seems you may have a missing file or the RS user has incorrect permissions to access that file

Comment: I have googled and everything I find is 5+ years old and about SQL 2008.  I have seen solutions around doing windows updates and checking the permissions on files but I would think if I didn't have permissions I would not be able to run reports at all.  Reports will work fine all day and then stop.  It's not just the reports from our app that stop, I can't even browse directly to the report server and get a folder list, which I can do when everything is working.  I'm stumped because of the seemingly randomness.

Comment: Here is what we finally ended up with since we could not figure it out.  Not the ideal solution but it works...  First we created a scheduled task to run every hour that simply connects to localhost/reports.  This keeps SSRS running.  The problem with that is after about a week or so it goes down again.  Googling why we came up with the answer that SSRS needs to clear out every once in a while.  So along with the hourly connect to localhost/reports to keep it alive we do a nightly restart of the SSRS service during a time where we have no activity.  Not the best solution but works for us.